# Xcode 10 image slicing not working as expected

Tags: nine-patch, xcode10, nsimageview

After updating to Xcode 10 my sliced images stopped working in macOS projects. It is working fine in iOS projects.
Here is an example of the image slice:

[image]

And here is how it looks at IB:

[image]

I have tried many different settings and slicing options.
I worked with this in previous version of Xcode and it was OK.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, it is xcode 10 bug. I installed 9.3 version and everything is ok.

Comment: Just installed macOS High Sierra with xcode 10 and the problem gone. So this is a bug in xcode 10 + Mojave combo.